# Personal Attributes, Influence and Importance of Japhet Among Noah's Sons

Tags: jewish-books, hebrew, torah-study, tanach, rabbis

Would you be so kind and provide brief, yet details information about personal attributes, influence and importance of **Japhet**, commonly agreed among Jews and also Hebrews, perhaps if possible by referring to the Holy Books (Torah and Tanach)?

Thanks so much!

[Reference](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/96265/dividing-the-world-for-the-sons-of-noah/96268#96268)

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Emma. Your post appears to contain two distinct questions, and is therefore likely to get closed as Too Broad. To prevent that you can [edit] out one of them and ask it separately. However, in this particular case the questions might be [off-topic for not being strictly about Judaism](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). To improve the chances of it being on-topic you can try to clarify precisely how they relate to Judaism (as opposed to historical facts about Jews or other biblical figures).